# Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why i'm getting this error?

> Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not
> recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See
> https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.
>
> - Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
>
> Please update the following components: SideEffect(NullComponent)

The app was working fine, went for few hours and came back found it giving me this error! one solution I found is removing  I removed it and the error went away, but the api i'm using didn’t work, so i'm looking for another solution!

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.103",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.7.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

For API call use "componentDidMount"
If it not help then need to see your code snapshot in order understand what is going on.